# How to use camera.dart and camera_screen.dart to capture the image by camera and then move it to the place holder in my flutter application

Tags: image, firebase, flutter, storage

I am using camera_screen.dart for camera preview and capture of the image using the following code

Actually hwen I am using image picker my application is crashing after camera capture where as there is no problem with gallery image.

So that is why I a want to use camera.dart and camera_screen.dart.

Please help me place  the captured image with the above procedure and place the cimage in my place holder or circular avatar. so that I want to further store the image into firebase storage.

```
     void updateUI(dynamic myPath) {
    setState(() {
      if (myPath == null) {
        myPath = 'images/cam.jpg';
        visibilityFlag2 = false;
        visibilityFlag1 = true;
        print('mypathh/.................$myPath');
        return;
      }
      //  myPath = 'images/exit.png';
      myppath = myPath;
      visibilityFlag2 = true;
      visibilityFlag1 = false;
      print('mypathhfgdfgdf/.................$myppath');
    });
  }




  void openImagePickerModal(BuildContext context) {
    final flatButtonColor = Theme
        .of(context)
        .primaryColor;
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            height: 180.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Visibility(
                  visible: visibilityFlag1,
                  child: Center(

                    child: FlatButton(

                     child: Text("Chose Image from Camera"),

                      onPressed: () async {
                        var ppath = await Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return CameraScreen();
                            },
                          ),
                        );


                        updateUI(ppath);
                        print('sdfbsdfbs.......$ppath}');
                      },


                      color: Colors.green,
                      textColor: Colors.white,

                  ),
                ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: visibilityFlag2,
                  child: Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 200.0,
                        child: Image.file(
                          File(myppath),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () async {
                        var ppath = await Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return CameraScreen();
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                        updateUI(ppath);
                        print('sdfbsdfbs.......$ppath}');
                        FirebaseStorage fs = FirebaseStorage.instance;

                        StorageReference rootReference = fs.ref();
                        Random random = new Random();
                        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(1000);
                        final StorageReference pictureFolderRef = rootReference
                            .child("images").child("image${randomNumber}");

                        pictureFolderRef.putFile(_image).onComplete.then((storageTask) async
                        {
                          String link = await storageTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
                          print("Image uploaded");
                          setState(() {
                            imageLink = link;

                          });
                        });

                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),



                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Chose Image From Gallery"),
                  onPressed: () async {
                     getImageFile(ImageSource.gallery);
                   // _image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

                    FirebaseStorage fs = FirebaseStorage.instance;

                    StorageReference rootReference = fs.ref();
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(1000);
                    final StorageReference pictureFolderRef = rootReference
                        .child("images").child("image${randomNumber}");

                    pictureFolderRef.putFile(_image).onComplete.then((storageTask) async
                    {
                      String link = await storageTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
                      print("Image uploaded");
                      setState(() {
                        imageLink = link;

                      });
                    });
                  },
                  color: Colors.green,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                ),


              ],
            ),
          );
        });
    //Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }


}
```

my camera_screen.dart coe is as follows:

```
 class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() {
    return _CameraScreenState();
  }
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State {
  CameraController controller;
  List cameras;
  int selectedCameraIdx;
  String imagePath;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    availableCameras().then((availableCameras) {
      cameras = availableCameras;

      if (cameras.length > 0) {
        setState(() {
          selectedCameraIdx = 0;
        });

        _initCameraController(cameras[selectedCameraIdx]).then((void v) {});
      } else {
        print("No camera available");
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Error: $err.code\nError Message: $err.message');
    });
  }

  Future _initCameraController(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller.dispose();
    }

    controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);

    // If the controller is updated then update the UI.
    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }

      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        print('Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Capture image'),
        backgroundColor: kActiveCardColour,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  _cameraTogglesRowWidget(),
                  _captureControlRowWidget(context),
                  Spacer()
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display Camera preview.
  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Loading',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    }

    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }

  /// Display the control bar with buttons to take pictures
  Widget _captureControlRowWidget(context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                backgroundColor: kActiveCardColour,
                onPressed: () {
                  _onCapturePressed(context);
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display a row of toggle to select the camera (or a message if no camera is available).
  Widget _cameraTogglesRowWidget() {
    if (cameras == null || cameras.isEmpty) {
      return Spacer();
    }

    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIdx];
    CameraLensDirection lensDirection = selectedCamera.lensDirection;

    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: FlatButton.icon(
            onPressed: _onSwitchCamera,
            icon: Icon(_getCameraLensIcon(lensDirection)),
            label: Text(
                "${lensDirection.toString().substring(lensDirection.toString().indexOf('.') + 1)}")),
      ),
    );
  }

  IconData _getCameraLensIcon(CameraLensDirection direction) {
    switch (direction) {
      case CameraLensDirection.back:
        return Icons.camera_rear;
      case CameraLensDirection.front:
        return Icons.camera_front;
      case CameraLensDirection.external:
        return Icons.camera;
      default:
        return Icons.device_unknown;
    }
  }

  void _onSwitchCamera() {
    selectedCameraIdx =
    selectedCameraIdx < cameras.length - 1 ? selectedCameraIdx + 1 : 0;
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIdx];
    _initCameraController(selectedCamera);
  }

  void _onCapturePressed(context) async {
    // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
    // catch the error.
    try {
      // Attempt to take a picture and log where it's been saved
      final path = join(
        // In this example, store the picture in the temp directory. Find
        // the temp directory using the `path_provider` plugin.
        (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
        '${DateTime.now()}.jpg',
      );
      print(path);
      await controller.takePicture(path);

      // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen
/*
      Navigator.pop(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomeNurseRegistration(
              myPath: path,
            ),
          ),);
*/
      Navigator.pop(context, path);
    } catch (e) {
      // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    String errorText = 'Error: ${e.code}\nError Message: ${e.description}';
    print(errorText);

    print('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
  }
}
```

In my project actually I have to capture the image by camera and upoad the captured image and gallery image both to firebase storage.

Please help me place the image first in the circular avatar below

```
  Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,

              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 100,
                backgroundColor: Color(0xff476cfb),
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: new SizedBox(
                    width: 180.0,
                    height: 180.0,
                    child: (_image!=null)?Image.file(_image, fit: BoxFit.fill,):Image.network(imageLink, fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.camera,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  openImagePickerModal(context);
                  //uploadPic(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
```

Then I have to store the images from camera nd gallery both into firebase storage. Please guide me.

Comment: my only issue or problem is How to comebcak and show the captured picture in circular avatar in my code . Please guide me

Comment: my only issue or problem is How to come back and show the captured picture in circular avatar in my code . Please guide me

Comment: Now Iam using the following code  camera_screen.dart  and preview_screen.dart as shown in the example  https://www.raywenderlich.com/4333657-using-the-camera-on-flutter#:~:text=camera_screen.,that%20image%20with%20your%20friends.